# SSIS Parent child configuration

Tags: ssis

I have one master pacakge and 20 child pacakges in ssis. I want make a single configuration file in master pacakge and save the connection string in that configuration file and pass the same connection string to its child pacakge . So that i have to change at one place and it will work for all child packages.
Please help me to solve this problem.
Thanks

Comment: I assume this is SQL 2008 R2 or earlier (please specify). If you take a look in your package configurations, you'll see that you can load variables from... a **parent** package. So basically you do not _push_ variables into children packages, you _pull_ them into the child from the parent by defining a config. The child knows nothing about the parent. If there is a matching variable in the parent it will populate it. If not it will throw a warning. See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/ms345179(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Exactly what @Nick.McDermaid said, only another way of thinking of it is that you don't PASS variables from the parent to the child.   Instead the child can INHERIT the variables of the parent.